# Is it possible to use Chrome Canary and Netbeans Connector?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, netbeans, google-chrome-canary

My default browser is Google Chrome, after knowing that Google Chrome canary has a dark theme I am convince to download and try it and the result is awesome.

Now I wanted to develop my project using Google Chrome Canary's dark theme, but the problem is I can't link Canary and Netbeans.

As you can see in the picture below the only available choices are `Embedded Webkit Browser` and `Chrome`.

[image]

What I've tried so far:

1. I already install Netbeans Connector extension in Canary

Comment: The second "Chrome" entry is just a repeat? Or a mislabeled Canary?

Comment: @Mario I am trying to use `With Netbeans Connector` so the only choices are those at the upper portion. The browser at the bottom doesn't use Netbeans Connector

Comment: Ah, okay. I missed the shading around those entries and the caption.

Comment: Thanks sir, yeah. :) Thank you so much for the interest.